# How to validate a form in JavaScript without jQuery validation plugin and without submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have this form in html and I want to validate this form when the user press `#btnPopup`, this button is not a submit one. How can I do this without using jQuery validation plugin, on a click button?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmUsers" data-userid="">
  <img id="btnClose" src="resources/img/close_window.png">
  <h2 id="popupTitle"></h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="txtUsername" placeholder="Please select username" required/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="level">Level:</label>
      <input type="number" id="level" name="txtLevel" placeholder="Please select level" required/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="registrationStatus">RegistrationStatus:</label>
      <select name="txtRegistrationStatus" id="registrationStatus" placeholder="Please select registration status" class="required">
        <option value="Registered">Registered</option>
        <option value="Unregistered">Unregistered</option>
      </select>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="registrationDate">RegistrationDate:</label>
      <input type="text" id="registrationDate" name="txtRegistrationDate" placeholder="Please select date" required/>
    </li>

    <div class="btnZone">
      <input class="btnDown" type="button" value=" " id="btnPopup" />
      <input class="btnDown" type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel">
    </div>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: what did you try so far? show us some code to work on it

Comment: `$(function() { $("#btnPopup").on("click",function() { /*validation here*/ });});`

Comment: function validateForm() {
    var emptyFields = $("input[value =]");
    if(emptyFields.size() > 0){
        emptyFields.each(function () {
            $(this).stop()
                .animate( { borderColor: "red"})
                .addClass("required");
            hidePopup();
        });
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax by sending your form input in parameters to achieve what your want and attach an event to your button.

```
$('#btnPopup').on('click', function(){

    // Fields validation

    if( validation ){
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "your_url",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'username' : $('#username').val(),
                'level' : $('#level').val()
                ...
            }
        })
        .done(function( result ) {
            // Do something
        })
        .fail(function(result, textStatus) {
            // Do something when error happened
        });

    }else{
        // Do something when your validations are bad.
    }

});
```

Don't forget to validate your parameter server side. Validation client side can be by passed easily. After that you can get the server response inside the ajax success callback

Comment: `data: $(this).closest("form").serialize()`

Comment: Doesn't make much validation, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your Form by attaching a "Click" listener on your "#btnPopup" and adding a simple submit inside it:

```
var myButton = document.getElementById("btnPopup");
myButton.addEventListener("click" , function(){
    /*
        --Your Validation logic goes here--
    */

    // You submit the Form when the Validation is over.
    document.getElementById("frmUsers").submit();
});
```

Now you can write your own Validation functions depending on what you want to validate your form against. A really simple and very basic validation would be to create a general function and validate each field on by one like the following :

```
function validate(inputField){
  var myInputField = document.forms["frmUsers"][inputField].value;

  // Add some simple Validation Rules 
  if(myInputField == null || myInputField == ""){
    // Do Something if validation fails [Eg: alert('error!!!');]
    return false;
  }
}
```

You can use the above function like :

```
validate("txtUsername");
```

You can apparently make a loop and pass through each field in your Form and validate it. Generally there are a lot of ways to validate a Form , the above example will get you in the right track though.

**Important:** This is a Client-Side validation though. Keep in mind that in 99 cases out of 100 you really need to have a Server-Side validation configured too. Client-Side validation is not 100% secure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. below is sample code which you can tweek and use

```js
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["frmUsers"]["registrationDate"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Registration date must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input class="btnDown" type="button" value=" " id="btnPopup" onclick="return validateForm();/>
```

Comment: And if there are empty fields, I should keep the modal on screeen and highlight the empty field with a red border. How can I do this?